# A game about defending a castle, with trading-card-like gameplay and aesthetic, in English and Czech

Tags: identify-this-game

There is a certain game I remember playing sometime in the 2000s.  My memories of it are rather faint, but here is what I remember:

- <del>The setting was, I think, some kind of a medieval fantasy, but I am not particularly sure.</del> (Missed the mark on this one.)
- The game ran on Windows 95 (it might have been 98, but not likely).
- The core gameplay was based on battling of some sort.  I think the objective was to defend a castle.
- Some graphics looked a bit like a trading card game.  There were some kinds of power-up/effect items displayed as vertical rectangles with an icon, a label, and (I think) a description (though the descriptions may have been hidden by default).  The labels were set in the Fixedsys font.  <del>Dice rolling may have been explicitly depicted.</del>
- The game came in two language versions: English and Czech (and I think no others).  I remember playing both.  One of the items/power-ups/cards was named Death (<del>Smrt or</del> *Smrtka*), illustrated with a skeleton.

Does this ring a bell?

Comment: I’m not much of a fan of those kinds of questions, but since they seem to be relatively well-received, I figured why not ask one myself?

Comment: Sounds like (a variant of) Magic the Gathering? I was a great fan of Master of Magic which was derived from it, but the described gameplay does not seem the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know what you mean. I think it was called Mravenci (Ants)

[image]
Image from http://echo_freeware10.sweb.cz/ants/ants_2.jpg

Comment: [Yes, that was definitely it.](http://echo_freeware10.sweb.cz/ants/ants_2.jpg)

Comment: Still downloadable from the author’s website: <http://panda38.sweb.cz/software.html>